# How to convert mmddyyyy date format to mm/dd/yyyy in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a dateformat

date="11032020"(mmddyyyy)

output expected:11/03/2020

I want to convert this to mm/dd/yyyy in nodejs.I am a begineer to nodejs.
I saw many posts where they convert from mm-dd-yyyy to different format or related.I tried converting to ISO but that did not work out.

I am not able to convert mmddyyyy to different format.

Could you please help me out in this.

Comment: `"11032020".match(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/).slice(1).join('/')`?

Comment: No need for a library to format a string like that

Comment: `date.substr(0, 2) + '/' + date.substr(2, 2) + '/' + date.substr(4, 4)`. No need to trot out a regular expression or an entire date-parsing library to simply extract some simple substrings from known positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain that the input is `MMDDYYYY` and don't need to validate it, you could use a regular expression:

```js
let format_date = input => input.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1/$2/$3")
format_date("11032020") // "11/03/2020"
```

Answer (score -1):

With moment.js you can do:

```js
const date = "11032020"
const res = moment(date, "MMDDYYYY").format('MM/DD/YYYY')

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: ...and enjoy [+72kB](https://bundlephobia.com/package/moment@2.29.1) of [legacy code](https://momentjs.com/docs/) added to your bundle for what can be done with a [single `.replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69438101/11299053)

Comment: ...wasn't my downvote, just in case

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov what if OP is also using moment.js for something else?